# Apply multiple conditional level groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

**Question 1:**

I have a data frame with two month value columns as `month1` and `month2`. If the value in `month1` column is not `NA`, then sum the corresponding `amount` values as per `month1` column. If the value in `month1` column is `NA`, then pick the corresponding value of 'month2' and search for it in `month1` column and perform sum.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'month1': [1, 2, 'NA', 1, 4, 'NA', 'NA'],
        'month2': ['NA', 5, 1, 2, 'NA', 1, 3],
        'amount': [10, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100]
    }
)
```

Desired output for question 1:

```
    month1  month2  sum_amount
0     1.0     NaN      60
1     2.0     5.0      20
2     NaN     1.0      60
3     1.0     2.0      60
4     4.0     NaN      60
5     NaN     1.0      60
6     NaN     3.0      0
```

**Question 2:**

I have a data frame with two month value columns as `month1` and `month2`. If the value in `month1` column is not `NA`, then sum the corresponding `amount` values as per `month2` column. If the value in `month1` column is `NA`, then pick the corresponding value of `month2` and search for it in `month2` column and perform sum.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'month1': [1, 2, 'NA', 1, 4, 'NA', 'NA'],
        'month2': ['NA', 5, 1, 2, 'NA', 1, 3],
        'amount': [10, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100]
    }
)
```

Desired Output for question 2:

```
    month1  month2  sum_amount
0     1.0     NaN      110
1     2.0     5.0      50
2     NaN     1.0      110
3     1.0     2.0      110
4     4.0     NaN      0
5     NaN     1.0      110
6     NaN     3.0      100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First replace strings `NA` to missing values, then aggregate `sum` to `Series`. Then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new column with missing values for non matched values, so replace `NaN`s with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and another column mapped, last replace non matched values in both columns to `0`:

```
df = df.replace('NA', np.nan)
s = df.groupby('month1')['amount'].sum()
df['sum_amount'] = df['month1'].map(s).fillna(df['month2'].map(s)).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   month1  month2  amount  sum_amount
0     1.0     NaN      10          60
1     2.0     5.0      20          20
2     NaN     1.0      40          60
3     1.0     2.0      50          60
4     4.0     NaN      60          60
5     NaN     1.0      70          60
6     NaN     3.0     100           0
```

And for second only change columns names in same solution:

```
df = df.replace('NA', np.nan)
s = df.groupby('month2')['amount'].sum()
df['sum_amount'] = df['month1'].map(s).fillna(df['month2'].map(s)).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   month1  month2  amount  sum_amount
0     1.0     NaN      10         110
1     2.0     5.0      20          50
2     NaN     1.0      40         110
3     1.0     2.0      50         110
4     4.0     NaN      60           0
5     NaN     1.0      70         110
6     NaN     3.0     100         100
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution is not the elegant one, but it works. Have a look.

The same part for both of your questions would be:

```
In  [1]: import pandas as pd    
         df = pd.DataFrame(
             {
                 'month1': [1, 2, 'NA', 1, 4, 'NA', 'NA'],
                 'month2': ['NA', 5, 1,  2, 'NA', 1, 3],
                 'amount': [10, 20, 40, 50, 60, 70, 100],
             }
         )

         def make_sum_amount(row, amount_sum):
             if row['month1'] == 'NA':
                 if row['month2'] == 'NA':
                     return 0
                 return amount_sum.get(row['month2'], 0)
             return amount_sum.get(row['month1'], 0)
```

Solution for the first question:

```
In  [2]: grouped_df = df[df['month1']!='NA'].groupby('month1').sum().reset_index()
         amount_sum = {k: v for k, v in zip(grouped_df['month1'], grouped_df['amount'])}
         df['sum_amount'] = df.apply(lambda row: make_sum_amount(row, amount_sum), axis=1)
         df

Out [2]:    month1  month2  amount  sum_amount
         0     1.0      NA      10          60
         1     2.0     5.0      20          20
         2      NA     1.0      40          60
         3     1.0     2.0      50          60
         4     4.0      NA      60          60
         5      NA     1.0      70          60
         6      NA     3.0     100           0
```

Solution for the second question:

```
In  [3]: grouped_df = df[df['month2']!='NA'].groupby('month2').sum().reset_index()
         amount_sum = {k: v for k, v in zip(grouped_df['month2'], grouped_df['amount'])}
         df['sum_amount'] = df.apply(lambda row: make_sum_amount(row, amount_sum), axis=1)
         df

Out [3]:    month1  month2  amount  sum_amount
         0     1.0      NA      10         110
         1     2.0     5.0      20          50
         2      NA     1.0      40         110
         3     1.0     2.0      50         110
         4     4.0      NA      60           0
         5      NA     1.0      70         110
         6      NA     3.0     100         100
```